Unable to start mongodb-community
I am trying to install Mongodb on my Mac (M2 chip)
I run the following:
brew tap mongodb/brew
brew install mongodb-community@7.0
brew services start mongodb-community@7.0

I then check if the service is running and check the logs
➜  brew services list
Name              Status       User  File
mongodb-community error  15872 foo ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist

➜  payload tail $(brew --prefix)/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
{"t":{"$date":"2024-08-07T17:23:20.516+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795902, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Closing WiredTiger","attr":{"closeConfig":"leak_memory=true,use_timestamp=false,"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-08-07T17:23:20.516+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"WTCHKPT",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":{"ts_sec":1723022600,"ts_usec":516819,"thread":"62910:0x2058c7ac0","session_name":"close_ckpt","category":"WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS","category_id":6,"verbose_level":"DEBUG_1","verbose_level_id":1,"msg":"saving checkpoint snapshot min: 2, snapshot max: 2 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0) base write gen: 48"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-08-07T17:23:20.537+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"WTRECOV",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":{"ts_sec":1723022600,"ts_usec":537513,"thread":"62910:0x2058c7ac0","session_name":"WT_CONNECTION.close","category":"WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS","category_id":30,"verbose_level":"DEBUG_1","verbose_level_id":1,"msg":"shutdown checkpoint has successfully finished and ran for 20 milliseconds"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-08-07T17:23:20.537+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"WTRECOV",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":{"ts_sec":1723022600,"ts_usec":537566,"thread":"62910:0x2058c7ac0","session_name":"WT_CONNECTION.close","category":"WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS","category_id":30,"verbose_level":"DEBUG_1","verbose_level_id":1,"msg":"shutdown was completed successfully and took 21ms, including 0ms for the rollback to stable, and 20ms for the checkpoint."}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-08-07T17:23:20.570+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger closed","attr":{"durationMillis":54}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-08-07T17:23:20.570+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22279,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"shutdown: removing fs lock..."}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-08-07T17:23:20.570+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784931, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-08-07T17:23:20.570+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now exiting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-08-07T17:23:20.570+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":8423404, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"mongod shutdown complete","attr":{"Summary of time elapsed":{"Statistics":{"Enter terminal shutdown":"0 ms","Step down the replication coordinator for shutdown":"0 ms","Time spent in quiesce mode":"0 ms","Shut down FLE Crud subsystem":"0 ms","Shut down MirrorMaestro":"0 ms","Shut down WaitForMajorityService":"1 ms","Shut down the transport layer":"0 ms","Shut down the global connection pool":"0 ms","Shut down the flow control ticket holder":"0 ms","Kill all operations for shutdown":"0 ms","Shut down all tenant migration access blockers on global shutdown":"0 ms","Shut down all open transactions":"0 ms","Acquire the RSTL for shutdown":"0 ms","Shut down the IndexBuildsCoordinator and wait for index builds to finish":"0 ms","Shut down the replica set monitor":"0 ms","Shut down the migration util executor":"0 ms","Shut down the TTL monitor":"0 ms","Shut down expired pre-images and documents removers":"0 ms","Shut down the storage engine":"54 ms","Wait for the oplog cap maintainer thread to stop":"0 ms","Shut down full-time data capture":"0 ms","shutdownTask total elapsed time":"55 ms"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-08-07T17:23:20.570+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":62}}

Any idea what that log shows?
===== EDIT =====
I tried a few other things:
➜  ps aux | grep mongod
grant            92174   0.0  0.0 41073264   1488 s000  S+    6:41pm   0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn --exclude-dir=.idea --exclude-dir=.tox mongod


➜ brew services list
Name              Status      User  File
mongodb-community error  3584 grant ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist

The contents of ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
        <string>/opt/homebrew/opt/mongodb-community/bin/mongod</string>
        <string>--config</string>
        <string>/opt/homebrew/etc/mongod.conf</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
        <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <false/>
        <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
        <string>/opt/homebrew</string>
        <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
        <string>/opt/homebrew/var/log/mongodb/output.log</string>
        <key>StandardOutPath</key>
        <string>/opt/homebrew/var/log/mongodb/output.log</string>
        <key>HardResourceLimits</key>
        <dict>
        <key>NumberOfFiles</key>
        <integer>64000</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>SoftResourceLimits</key>
        <dict>
        <key>NumberOfFiles</key>
        <integer>64000</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    </plist>

    cat /opt/homebrew/var/log/mongodb/output.log
    Output:

    cat /opt/homebrew/etc/mongod.conf 
    Output:
    systemLog:
      destination: file
      path: /opt/homebrew/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
      logAppend: true
    storage:
      dbPath: /opt/homebrew/var/mongodb
    net:
      bindIp: 127.0.0.1, ::1
      ipv6: true

    ls -l /opt/homebrew/var/log/mongodb/ 
    Output:
    -rw-------  1 grant  admin  10183  7 Aug 19:03 mongo.log
    -rw-r--r--  1 grant  admin      0  7 Aug 18:39 output.log

    /opt/homebrew/opt/mongodb-community/bin/mongod --config /opt/homebrew/etc/mongod.conf
    Output:


Have you followed the official guide? in that case, have you've allowed mongodb to run in System Preferences? System Preferences > Security and Privacy > General

I followed the guide at https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/. I have not "have you've allowed mongodb to run in System Preferences"

when I first started mongo via brew, as a service, OSX Prompted me to allow mongo to the network, that is what is added to System Preferences. If mongo is not allowed to use the network, it will not be able to map a port and will shutdown immediately after startup.

Not network, but security reasons, like the guide indicates could happen.

I am on Sonoma. When I go to System Preferences I see "Privacy & Security" option on the left but once clicked there is no "General" tab / option. I see "Security" section but it only show Firevault which is disabled.

Also, simply run mongod --dbpath /opt/homebrew/var/mongodb and see what the output is, the output from tail is limited to XX amount of rows, some information is missing.

You need to show some more line from log than just the latest 10 lines

The log you provided from MongoDB indicates that the mongodb server is starting up but then shuts down immediately.
The log entries related to 'WiredTiger' sho wthat Mongodb's storage engine is closing and shuting down. WiredTiger is the default storage engine user by mongodb
{"t":{"$date":"2024-08-07T17:23:20.516+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795902, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Closing WiredTiger","attr":{"closeConfig":"leak_memory=true,use_timestamp=false,"}}


{"t":{"$date":"2024-08-07T17:23:20.570+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger closed","attr":{"durationMillis":54}}

The exit code 62 generally indicated that mongodb encountered an error during startup or shutdown.
{"t":{"$date":"2024-08-07T17:23:20.570+08:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":62}}

Potential causes:

File system permission
Conflicting processes
Configuration issues

Try uninstall and re-install mongodb. But this time try this command,
brew update
brew uninstall mongodb-community
brew install mongodb-community

or
brew update
brew uninstall mongodb-community@7.0
brew install mongodb-community@7.0
brew services start mongodb-community@7.0

To check if it has started,
ps aux | grep -v grep | grep mongod

Just in case you can do it this operation with sudo


I have added a little more info. Dont know if that helps?

Could you share this details,
cat /opt/homebrew/var/log/mongodb/output.log
cat /opt/homebrew/etc/mongod.conf
ls -l /opt/homebrew/var/log/mongodb/
and also try manuel start,
/opt/homebrew/opt/mongodb-community/bin/mongod --config /opt/homebrew/etc/mongod.conf

Ok I have added the logs

From https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/exit-codes/ the code 62 is...

Returned by mongod when the datafiles in --dbpath are incompatible with the version of mongod currently running.
To resolve data incompatibility issues after upgrading, please refer to the release notes for your version of MongoDB and search for "Changes Affecting Compatibility."

The simples way to prove it is correct is to create an empty /opt/homebrew/var/mongodb_test and change /opt/homebrew/etc/mongod.conf to point dbPath to that location.
Mongo will initialise the wt files on first run.

Thanks. I tried this but get the error:
brew services start mongodb-community
Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error
Try re-running the command as root for richer errors.
Error: Failure while executing; /bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist exited with 5.

I restarted mongodb using brew and still get the error:
mongodb-community error  512 root ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist

Any details of the nature of the error? Does the new directory have the same permissions /owner as the original one?

It was potentially a permissions issue
sudo chmod -R 0755 /opt/homebrew/var/mongodb
sudo rm /opt/homebrew/var/mongodb/mongod.lock

or a config issue
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: /opt/homebrew/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
  logAppend: true

storage:
  dbPath: /opt/homebrew/var/mongodb

net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1, ::1
  ipv6: true

